# Accelerating launch process of Apps in Firemonkey

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, launch

When creating multi-platform applications at Delphi Firemonkey, it takes a long amount of time (4~6 seconds) to load, even when there's absolutely nothing but a brand new blank screen with no objects.

What can we do to accelerate the launching proccess?

Comment: Not much really. The FireMonkey library is just slow to start up in general.

Comment: Write your application in Java, using native tools, then it will start much faster

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wish I could.

Comment: Do you intend to target any platform other than Android? If not, you could be making a mistake. The whole purpose of Firemonkey is for multi-platform support.

Comment: This is being developed on `Firemonkey` to support both `iOS` and `Android`.

Comment: @ThisGuy I don't understand your comment - was in in response to mine? If so, that's actually the opposite of my point.

Comment: @JerryDodge I guess this is a response to me, actually.

Comment: was in response to Holmes and needing to use Fire monkey for iOS and Android. Seems like each new release of Delphi things get a tiny bit quicker but then there's more bugs and issues added to a list that they never seem to work on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FireMonkey requires a complete runtime environment of its own which runs on top of the host platform.  This runtime provides the rendering engine and other abstractions necessary to enable the cross-platform architecture of FireMonkey to execute on the specific hardware platform of a given application.

Any and every application built using FireMonkey includes a copy of this runtime environment and has to load and initialise that environment before the application code itself can run.

As a result, FireMonkey applications are necessarily and unavoidably larger and slower to start than applications built using the platform native tools which do not need this additional runtime support.